# chrome.webNavigation undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing my first Google extension code, and I am getting a weird error I have never seen in my life.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCompleted' of undefined background.js:4
(anonymous function)
```

I am decently new to Javascript btw (have extensive knowledge in Java though).

My code looks like this:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(){//error right here
if(hasHostSuffix(document.URL,'mysite.com'))
{
    console.log("Web navigation commited!");
    var links = document.getElementsByName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(links[i].getAttribute("href"));
        if(links[i].style.backgroundColor='#272727')
        {
            links[i].className="gone";
        }
    }
}
});
```

I haven't been able to find any solid information on my I am getting this error.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

EDIT:

Was brought to my attention that I forgot some vital info xD My manfiest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
...,
"permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
],
...,
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["http://www.mysite.com/*"],
        "css":["ur_customstyle.css"],
        "js":["background.js"]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: webNavigation must be undefined. Have you added the permission in your  manifest? - http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html

Comment: `chrome.webNavigation` evaluates to `undefined`, so you cannot access the property `onCompleted`. Were does this get set? (edit: see above)

Comment: @Rick That is what I was thinking, but I have the permission (Just forgot to add my manifest into my post o.O).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`chrome.webNavigation`, as most chrome.* APIs, can only be accessed from the background script of an extension, not from content scripts. Although your file is named `background.js`, your manifest shows that you are using it as a content script.

It is right to use a content script in this case because you need to interact with the DOM. From the fragment of code you posted, it seems that you don't need to use the webNavigation API. You can simply set your content script in your manifest to `run_at: document_end`, and it will run as soon as the DOM is complete. Check http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: Is there a way to use webNavigation in content script?

Comment: @KevenWang, no, there's none.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I thought this was an issue with my permissions and so it was undefined because my .manifest file had something wrong with it, but actually it was just trying to reference it in a content script.

Comment: @KevenWang as already said there's none and you can see that on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#webextension_apis) (I know your comment is old but I need to remember this link so posted the comment).

Answer (score 34):

On top of @rsanchez answer, if you call a `chrome.webNavigation` in the background script of your extension, but still have this error, you may also need to add the `webNavigation` permission in your `manifest.json`.

```
"permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
  ]
```

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation) | [Chrome Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>you need to make sure in your `manifest.json` the extension is registered with `persistent: false`</strike>

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "./scripts/saving/extension/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false // <---- HERE!!!!!
}
```

per what is said in here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

> The only occasion to keep a background script persistently active is if the extension uses chrome.webRequest API to block or modify network requests. The webRequest API is incompatible with non-persistent background pages.

**!!! AND ALSO !!!**

(if it was `persistent: true`)

you need to UNLOAD the extension and load it again

**UPDATE:**

turned out it's all irrelevant

in Chrome 72 what happens is that the extension needs to be always unloaded and loaded back anew

simple refresh/reload throws this problem